# SVG stroke with different linecaps

Tags: svg

Is it possible to have a SVG line with 1 rounded end (linecap) and 1 but or square end. I don't think that this question needs to be more descriptive, but this line of text is required by Stackoverflow question validator.

Comment: Can you tell us what did you try before post this question ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using 2 stacked svg line elements with different width values, like so:

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="30"  stroke-linecap="round" />
    <line x1="30" y1="100" x2="190" y2="100" stroke="red"  stroke-width="30"/>
</svg>
```

Using just 1 svg line element with multiple linecap values, as far as I can tell, is not possible.